# Sip Server on Java

Tags: java, сервер, sip

Как написать SIP сервер на java?
Есть код, но как этот сервер запустить я так и не понял

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.sip.*;


public class EchoServlet extends SipServlet {


    protected HashMap _addresses = new HashMap();


    protected void doInvite(SipServletRequest req) throws IOException {
        req.createResponse(SipServletResponse.SC_OK).send();
    }


    protected void doRegister(SipServletRequest req) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String aor = req.getFrom().getURI().toString().toLowerCase();
        synchronized (_addresses) {
            if (req.getExpires() != 0) {
                _addresses.put(aor, req.getAddressHeader("Contact").getURI());
            }
            else {
                _addresses.remove(aor);
            }
        }
        req.createResponse(SipServletResponse.SC_OK).send();
    }


    protected void doMessage(SipServletRequest req) throws IOException, ServletException {
        SipURI uri = null;
        synchronized (_addresses) {
            // Get the previous registered address for the sender.
            uri = (SipURI) _addresses.get(req.getFrom().getURI().toString().toLowerCase());
        }
        if (uri == null) {
            // Reject the message if it is not from a registered user.
            req.createResponse(SipServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN).send();
            return;
        }

        // We accept the instant message by returning 200 OK response.
        req.createResponse(SipServletResponse.SC_OK).send();

        // Create an echo SIP MESSAGE request with the same content.
        SipServletRequest echo = req.getSession().createRequest("MESSAGE");
        String charset = req.getCharacterEncoding();
        if (charset != null) {
            echo.setCharacterEncoding(charset);
        }
        echo.setRequestURI(uri);
        echo.setContent(req.getContent(), req.getContentType());
        // Send the echo MESSAGE request back to Windows Messenger.
        echo.send();
    }


    protected void doSuccessResponse(SipServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Print out when the echo message was accepted.
        if (resp.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("MESSAGE")) {
            System.out.println("\"" + resp.getRequest().getContent() + "\" was accepted: " + resp.getStatus());
        }
    }


    protected void doErrorResponse(SipServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Print out when the echo message was rejected/
        if (resp.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("MESSAGE")) {
            System.out.println("\"" + resp.getRequest().getContent() + "\" was rejected: " + resp.getStatus());
        }
    }


    protected void doBye(SipServletRequest req) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Accept session termination by returning 200 OK response.
        req.createResponse(SipServletResponse.SC_OK).send();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Этот код использует древнюю спецификацию [JSR 116: SIP Servlet API](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7209-sip_servlet-1.0-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) и для его запуска, как водится в Java EE мире, требуется собрать проект в виде `.sar`-файла и развернуть в контейнере SIP-сервлетов (подобно тому как для для выполнения web-сервлетов нужен контейнер web-сервлетов). Идея тут в том, что есть некий готовый SIP-сервер, поддерживающий данную спецификацию, и вы пишите для него свое бизнес-приложение.

Хорошая новость в том, что с тех пор вышла новая версия спецификации [JSR 289: SIP Servlet v1.1](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=289) с "современными" штуками типа аннотаций. И, похоже, даже существует и поддерживается сервер, который умеет с этим работать - [RestComm](https://github.com/RestComm/sip-servlets).

Про все это дело даже есть книга *Understanding SIP Servlets 1.1 (Chris Boulton ,‎ Kristoffer Gronowski)*.